# Truth Functions with connectives

Tags: logic

I have the number of truth functions $f$ on $n$ propositional variables with a property f(T,T,....,T)=T is $2^{2^{n}-1}$.

I have the question: Can these be expressed at the truth function of formula of $n$ variables using only ∧, ∨?

I am unsure of what this question is asking me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. Take any function for which $f(F,F,F,...,F)=T$

It should be clear that any expression built up from $\land$'s and $\lor$'s alone will evaluate to $F$ when filling in $F$ for all of its atomic propositions, and hence there is no such expression that can capture this kind of truth-function.

Comment: ah yes that makes sense. I didn't think about that situation. thanks for your help!

Comment: @juper Glad I could help! :)